# How to pass values to a user control in winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a winforms app that where I programmatically create a user control and pass values to it.  When I run the program all the variables in the user control are null.  I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  When I look up similar programs it looks like I have the same code, but it's not working.  Maybe someone on here can help.

Here is the main form code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;

namespace AddPanel
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            DisplayImage();
        }


        private void DisplayImage()
        {

            FileStream fs = new FileStream("ntst.jpg", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);

            cameraTable = (from x in db.CamTable1s
                           select x).ToList();

            test nt = new test();
            nt.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(33, 20);
            nt.Name = "test1";
            nt.usrID = "username";
            nt.IPadd = "ipaddress";
            nt.pswd = "password";
            nt.ws = fs;
            nt.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(408, 266);
            this.Controls.Add(nt);

        }    

    }
}
```

The user control code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

using AForge;
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Controls;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;

namespace AddPanel
{
    public partial class test : UserControl
    {
        public string IPadd { get; set; }
        public string usrID { get; set; }
        public string pswd { get; set; }
        public string filename { get; set; }
        public FileStream ws { get; set; }


        public test()
        {

            JPEGStream jpegSource1 = new JPEGStream("http://" + IPadd + "/jpg/image.jpg?resolution=320x240");
            jpegSource1.Login = usrID;
            jpegSource1.Password = pswd;
            jpegSource1.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(jpegSource1_NewFrame);
            //source1.VideoSourceError += new VideoSourceErrorEventHandler(source1_VideoSourceError);
            jpegSource1.VideoSourceError += new VideoSourceErrorEventHandler(jpegSource1_VideoSourceError);
            Player1.VideoSource = jpegSource1;

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void jpegSource1_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            Bitmap image = new Bitmap(eventArgs.Frame, 320, 240);

            image.Save(ws, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        }

        void jpegSource1_VideoSourceError(object sender, VideoSourceErrorEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            //Error handler
            Debug.WriteLine(eventArgs.Description);

            Bitmap ErPic = new Bitmap(320, 240);
            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(ErPic))
            {
                using (var arialFontLarge = new Font("Arial", 15))
                {
                    g.DrawString("Camera Offline", arialFontLarge, Brushes.White, 75, 100);
                }

            }
            ErPic.Save(ws, ImageFormat.Bmp);
        }

        private void StartBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Player1.VideoSource.Start();
        }

        private void StopBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Player1.VideoSource.Stop();
            ws.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where/when do you see these null values

Comment: Do you mean values passed to jpegSource1 are null? You are populating them in the usercontrol's constructor and are not initializing them before. So, they will have default values for strings (null) and null for classes.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET they are null when I run debug and check the "IPadd" in the user control.

Comment: But at what *point*. If you check in the constructor, the assignment hasn't happened yet. If you check afterwards, than that seems like a serious problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my understanding of using variables between forms was wrong.

I should have put

```
public string IPadd { get; set; }
public string usrID { get; set; }
public string pswd { get; set; }
public string filename { get; set; }
public FileStream ws { get; set; }
```

in Form1 and then accessed them in test.  Like this:
Form1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;

using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Controls;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;

namespace AddPanel
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string iPadd;
        public string IPadd
        {
            get { return iPadd;}
            set
            {
                iPadd = value;

            }
        }

        private string usrID;
        public string UsrID
            {
            get { return usrID; }
            set
            {
                usrID = value;
            }
        }

        private string Pswd;
        public string pswd
        { 
            get{return Pswd;}
            set
            {
                Pswd = value;
            }
        }
        private string Filename;
        public string filename
        {
            get { return Filename; }
            set
            {
                Filename = value;
            }
         }

        public Form1()
        {


            InitializeComponent();


            DisplayImage();
        }


        private void DisplayImage()
        {



            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);


            UsrID = "webservice";
            IPadd = "10.108.212.100";
            pswd = "E4emw@tch!ngU";
            WS = fs;

            test nt = new test();
            nt.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(33, h);
            nt.Name = "test1";
            nt.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(408, 266);
            this.Controls.Add(nt);

        } 

    }
}
```

Then I can access those variables in test like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

using AForge;
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Controls;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;

namespace AddPanel
{
    public partial class test : UserControl
    {    

        public test()
        {
            Form1 f1 = new Form1();
            JPEGStream jpegSource1 = new JPEGStream("http://" + f1.IPadd + "/jpg/image.jpg?resolution=320x240");
            jpegSource1.Login = f1.UsrID;
            jpegSource1.Password = f1.pswd;
            jpegSource1.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(jpegSource1_NewFrame);
            //source1.VideoSourceError += new VideoSourceErrorEventHandler(source1_VideoSourceError);
            jpegSource1.VideoSourceError += new VideoSourceErrorEventHandler(jpegSource1_VideoSourceError);
            Player1.VideoSource = jpegSource1;

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void jpegSource1_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            Bitmap image = new Bitmap(eventArgs.Frame, 320, 240);

            image.Save(ws, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        }

        void jpegSource1_VideoSourceError(object sender, VideoSourceErrorEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            //Error handler
            Debug.WriteLine(eventArgs.Description);

            Bitmap ErPic = new Bitmap(320, 240);
            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(ErPic))
            {
                using (var arialFontLarge = new Font("Arial", 15))
                {
                    g.DrawString("Camera Offline", arialFontLarge, Brushes.White, 75, 100);
                }

            }
            ErPic.Save(ws, ImageFormat.Bmp);
        }

        private void StartBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Player1.VideoSource.Start();
        }

        private void StopBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Player1.VideoSource.Stop();
            ws.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are actually creating a new Form1 in your usercontrol that is separate from the Form1 that is hosting your usercontrol. If you are going to do it this way, assign your form1 to the usercontrols parent property then cast it to form1. I would still do it the way that I suggested in my answer, that way your usercontrol is not required to know the internals of its parent.

Comment: I am running into this problem right now. I will look up what you suggested

Answer (score 3):

Your UserControls constructor gets run when you new up your UserControl, you are setting your values after the fact. I would personally either create a constructor that you can pass in your initial settings or make a method that you execute to initialize it after you populate your values.

Something like this:

```
public partial class test : UserControl
{
    public string IPadd { get; set; }
    public string usrID { get; set; }
    public string pswd { get; set; }
    public string filename { get; set; }
    public FileStream ws { get; set; }

    public test()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public test(string Ip, string Id, string Pass, string file, FileStream stream )
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        IPadd = Ip;
        usrID = Id;
        pswd = Pass;
        filename = file;
        ws = stream;

        JPEGStream jpegSource1 = new JPEGStream("http://" + IPadd + "/jpg/image.jpg?resolution=320x240");
        jpegSource1.Login = usrID;
        jpegSource1.Password = pswd;
        jpegSource1.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(jpegSource1_NewFrame);
        source1.VideoSourceError += new VideoSourceErrorEventHandler(source1_VideoSourceError);
        pegSource1.VideoSourceError += new VideoSourceErrorEventHandler(jpegSource1_VideoSourceError);
        Player1.VideoSource = jpegSource1;

    }
}
```

Comment: This set the values like I wanted, thank you for that.  Now I need to figure out another error: when I click the start button it gives an error for "Player1.VideoSource.Start();" Any ideas?

Comment: What is the error? is your start button on the usercontrol or on the containing form?

Comment: NullReferenceException was unhandled.  It is in the usercontrol.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line and check what is null. Player1 or Videosource

Comment: It looks like Videosource is null.

Comment: Make sure that your jpegSource1 actually has a value and that VideoSource is not null in your constructor where you assign it

Comment: Well in the code it has "jpegSource1 = new JPEGStream("http:..." then "Player1.VideoSource = jpegSource1;" so shouldn't videoSource not be null?

Comment: It depends whether or not the stream actually got created, you may want to move your jpegSource1 declaration outside of the constructor and make it a class level variable just incase the Garbage Collector is disposing of it.

Comment: is a class level variable the same as a global variable?

Comment: Not quite, Global would be application scoped, class in this case would be UserControl1 scoped i.e the containing class.

Comment: It wouldn't let me because "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'AddPanel.test.IPadd.get'"

Comment: the problem is that I can't use any of the values.  Like if I put a textbox in the usercontrol and set textBox1.Text = usrID.  In debug usrID will have the right value, but textbox1.Text is still null.  How could I fix this problem?

Comment: Make sure you set the textbox text after you set the value for UId

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I am.

Comment: then it should have a value unless you are calling InitializeComponent after the fact

Comment: I'm putting it right after "ws = stream;" from your code section above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65725/discussion-between-mark-hall-and-user3634308).